# php7/pear showing parse error when requiring files

Tags: php, pear, php-7

I have a legacy site (not written by me) that has been on a server with php5 on it for the last several years. I am in the process of creating a new server with php7 on it and testing what works and is broken.

the site uses pear by including the file `pear/lib/DB.php`. i created a brand new page that only has the code

```
<?php

require_once( "DB.php" );

?>
```

this presents the exact same error as the full site.

the error that's being presented is

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /local/sites/php/pear/lib/DB.php on line 310
```

the site only requires DB.php because I have added Pear to the php.ini in `include_path`

checking the version of Pear gives me the following
$ pear version

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.3
PHP Version: 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
Zend Engine Version: 3.0.0
Running on: Linux cdc-migration-0d 3.13.0-103-generic #150-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 10:34:17 UTC 2016 x86_64
```

from my research it shows the latest version of Pear is php7 compatible, so these should work together. any idea why just requiring the `DB.php` on a test page would immediately generate the parsing error?

edit:
the code in the pear file that is generating the error is as follows

```
function &factory($type, $options = false)
    {
        if (!is_array($options)) {
            $options = array('persistent' => $options);
        }

        if (isset($options['debug']) && $options['debug'] >= 2) {
            // expose php errors with sufficient debug level
            include_once "DB/{$type}.php";
        } else {
            @include_once "DB/{$type}.php";
        }

        $classname = "DB_${type}";

        if (!class_exists($classname)) {
            $tmp = PEAR::raiseError(null, DB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND, null, null,
                                    "Unable to include the DB/{$type}.php file",
                                    'DB_Error', true);
            return $tmp;
        }

                @$obj =& new $classname; // ##### this is line 310 that generates the error #####

        foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
            $test = $obj->setOption($option, $value);
            if (DB::isError($test)) {
                return $test;
            }
        }

        return $obj;
    }
```

Comment: Well, what is in line 310 of that file? Could you please post the section of that file with a few lines above and below that line?

Comment: And, just by the way: I am a bit wondering about that _very_ strange path you cite: `/local/sites/...`. That does _not_ look like Ubuntu at all...

Comment: @arkascha i added the function that generates that error to the original question. as far as the strange path, my predecessors used non-typical installation paths (it's a pain), i have so far gone with the "if it's not broke" philosophy but that may change with this server upgrade. all i did to duplicate what they had before was change the root path when prompted by `go-pear.phar`

Comment: That line indeed is a syntax error... I wonder where it comes from this looks like a manual modification. Look at it! Its style is completely different from the result of the function. It is the only line that has a different (wrong) indentation. It has got the silly `@` in front of it. In short: that line looks fishy.

Comment: About the custom paths... That also reads as if manual, "wild" installations were done. And the question is _why_? To be able to do manual manipulations? Why not use the prepared and robust packages offered for Ubuntu?

Comment: @arkascha well it comes form the pear installation i did just today, i think the indentation is from me modifying the line to try and troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@$obj =& new $classname;
```

Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated since PHP 5.3. http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

This is PHP4 style of writing PHP.

Write instead :

```
$obj = new $classname;
```

This has been removed as of PHP7.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.new-by-ref

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.new-by-ref

Comment: However here (http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) it reads that "New objects cannot be assigned by reference" any more. It is a backward compatible change.

Comment: I guess we we're on the same road to salvation. Thanks @arkascha

Comment: you are correct, it is php4, and it is in use because i am idiot. i performed the new install of pear on our old server, not the new one we copied for this purpose. therefore the DB.php that was found was not the latest, php7 compatible version, but rather a legacy version written in php4. once i performed the update on the correct server, it copied a new version of DB.php (https://github.com/pear/DB/blob/trunk/DB.php) and was able to require it without error.

Comment: Happy you figured it out :)